# Application's memory increase continuously when I use BeginAcceptTcpClient

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, tcplistener

I'm writing a Windows Service which handles requests from Client. To listen the requests I use BeginAcceptTcpClient in a While loop.

```
while (stopListenning == false)
{
    tcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(RequestHandler), tcpListener);
}
```

I used Windows Task Manager to monitor the Windows Service's process and I detected the memory increase continuously while there wasn't requests sent to Windows Service. I tried many way to fix this problem but without result. Everyone please helps me.

Answer (score 0):

You have a while loop that allocates memory on the heap via the  `new AsyncCallback(...)`

This will increase the memory every time the loop executes. If the tcpListener keeps a reference to each AsyncCallback instance, then these will not be garbage collected and your memory use will just grow and grow. If no references are maintained then eventually the GC will kick in and your memory use will decrease.

Comment: Thanks Owen. Are there any suggestions for my case? I want the Windows Service listening the request everytime. If receive a new request then there is a asynchronous method to handle it and the main thread keeps listening another one.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem for myself after read this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f.aspx

The problem is I didn't use ManualResetEvent because I had a misunderstand about it. Now everything is ok.